# Ubuntu slows down dramatically after about 3 hours usage

Tags: 14.04

I have a situation whereby Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop slows down dramatically after a few hours usage. I asked a question ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768071/mouse-pointer-icon-on-vga-screen-changes-by-itself)) last week about my mouse pointer icon changing by itself. I've noticed over the last few days that this change is coinciding with a massive slowdown in Ubuntu - typing is slow, changing tabs and windows is slow and clunky etc.

I have 16gb of RAM installed and there's loads free when I use `watch -n 5 free -m` so I don't think that's the issue.

If I restart the system then everything goes back to normal and Ubuntu performs very well for a few hours until this happens again.

Has anyone any idea what could be causing this issue?

I'm not sure if this is at all relevant, but this installation was a restored clone from another, higher spec machine. Would this have anything to do with it?

Edit: I've just noticed that when I restart my system the graphics become very blocky. This has also happened over the last few days but I didn't put 2+2 together and link it with the issue above. To solve the blocky graphics issue earlier this week I tinkered around with AMD Catalyst and when I restarted the system the graphics were ok. The driver I'm using is: `fglrx-updates (proprietary)`. Anyone any idea what's going on here and how I can fix it?

Here's my specs (shortened as question has too much text):

```
description: Notebook
  product: 80F0 (LENOVO_MT_80F0_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo B50-45)
  vendor: LENOVO
  version: Lenovo B50-45
  serial: 3819047600004
  width: 64 bits
   *-cpu
        description: CPU
        product: AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
        vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
        physical id: 4
        bus info: cpu@0
        version: AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
        serial: NotSupport
        slot: Socket FT3b
        size: 1400MHz
        capacity: 1800MHz
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 100MHz
    *-memory
        description: System Memory
        size: 16GiB
      *-bank:0
           description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
           product: CT102464BF160B.C16
           physical id: 0
           serial: 1246F5A4
           slot: DIMM 0
           size: 8GiB
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
      *-bank:1
           description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
           product: CT102464BF160B.C16
           physical id: 1
           serial: 1246F5A3
           slot: DIMM 1
           size: 8GiB
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
       *-display
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
           vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
           physical id: 1
           bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
   *-scsi:0
        physical id: 1
        logical name: scsi0
        capabilities: emulated
      *-disk
           description: ATA Disk
           product: Samsung SSD 850
           physical id: 0.0.0
           bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
           logical name: /dev/sda
           version: EMT0
           serial: S2MRNXAH315576B
           size: 232GiB (250GB)
           capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
           configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=6115241f
```

Edit: Agghh. Was having a good day so far today but the problem just happened again. Here's the output from /var/log/Xorg.0.log that somebody might be able to decipher:

```
[    11.941] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    11.943] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    11.947] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    11.948] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    11.949] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    18.797] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    18.800] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    18.803] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    18.804] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    35.168] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-DC6B80E1F93F4FDB91E75CD00B96157EEC008205.xkm
[    36.124] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    36.125] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    36.129] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    36.130] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    36.902] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    36.904] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    36.908] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    36.909] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    36.909] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    36.909] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    36.909] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    36.909] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    36.910] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    37.336] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    37.337] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    37.341] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    37.342] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    37.508] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7C46A88197A2CF60980B264FE380C48E924DD339.xkm
[    37.544] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7C46A88197A2CF60980B264FE380C48E924DD339.xkm
[    38.360] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    38.361] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    38.366] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    38.367] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    38.367] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    38.367] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    38.367] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    38.367] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    38.367] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    38.367] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    38.368] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    38.673] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    38.675] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    38.678] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    38.679] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    38.680] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    41.240] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-0DF9A6CCA6AEFB68925697A43C309A4377FEC7B2.xkm
[    53.271] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    53.273] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    53.276] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    53.277] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    53.280] (WW) fglrx(0): Failed to get EDID by ACPI
[    53.282] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output DFP1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49352
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    53.285] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    53.286] (II) fglrx(0): User Preference Output CRT1 using refresh rate 60.0 Hz.
```

Thanks for looking. Hopefully someone can help. I'm going to restart the system now. My guess is the blocky graphics will be back when I do.

Edit: Yes indeed. Blocky graphics back. This is very frustrating as the performance is great until this happens. I'm going to change the driver then change it back again.

Comment: What happens if you use the open source GPU drivers?

Comment: I'll give it a go now and see what happens

Comment: I'm unable to use my dual monitors when I select the open source driver!!

Comment: Could you make due without them for a test run? We're trying to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: I probably could but it would be very painful. I'll stay on just the laptop and open source driver for the rest of the afternoon

Comment: If your graphics hardware is causing the problem there will be something in /var/log/Xorg.*.log (usually a 0) or dmesg that will explain it. have a look in there and post any errors towards the end of the files. the proprietary AMD Catalyst drivers are known to be buggy and so might struggle with multiple monitors.

Comment: The issue just happened again (first time today) so I've updated my question with the output in Xorg.0.log. Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: this shows the screen loosing connection with monitor a few times, 
have you checked your display cables ? they might be going out of spec after a while and triggering a display bug.

Might be worth leaving this system running overnight/weekend running a reasonably heay load with the monitors off and see if when you come back to it the problem has occured. If it hasn't then it would seem like the monitor cables are worth swapping

Comment: I think that happens when I lock Ubuntu. Monitors go to sleep. I'll leave it on overnight next week and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Posting how I sorted this issue in case anyone comes across something similar in the future.

I re-installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the machine in question and the open source graphics driver immediately recognised the dual monitors. I've been using it for 2 days with no issues whatsoever.

It appears the issues above were caused by the buggy AMD proprietary drivers. I've had none of them since I moved to the open source driver.

And I guess the open source driver didn't originally pick up the dual monitors because I restored an image made from a different machine to this one. A clean install sorted that out.

Thanks to all for their assistance